# Add CSS in Symfony2 twig express

Tags: php, css, symfony, twig

In Twig HTML file here is a very normal line:

```
{{ 'layout.logged_in_as'|trans({'%username%': app.user.username}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
```

How to add a `<strong></strong>` tag to wrap username?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~` is Twig's string concatenation operator. From [Twig's docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html):

> ~: Converts all operands into strings and concatenates them.
>   `{{ "Hello " ~ name ~ "!" }}` would return `Hello John!` (assuming `name` is `'John'`).

In your case, this should translate to something like:

```
{{ 'layout.logged_in_as'|trans({'%username%': '<b>'~app.user.username~'</b>'}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
```

Or perhaps:

```
{% set boldUsername = '<strong>' ~ app.user.username ~ '</strong>' %}
{{ 'layout.logged_in_as'|trans({'%username%': boldUsername}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
```

If autoescaping of the html is a problem, you may need to apply the [raw filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html):

```
{% set boldUsername = '<strong>' ~ app.user.username ~ '</strong>' %}
{{ 'layout.logged_in_as'|trans({'%username%': boldUsername}, 'FOSUserBundle')|raw }}
```

Finally, if you prefer making styling in css (who doesn't), add a <span> with a class instead of <strong>:

```
{% set usernameMarkup = '<span class="username">' ~ app.user.username ~ '</span>' %}
{{ 'layout.logged_in_as'|trans({'%username%': usernameMarkup}, 'FOSUserBundle')|raw }}
```

And in a css file:

```
.username { font-weight: bold; }
```

Comment: The following works: set boldUsername = '<strong>' ~ app.user.username ~ '</strong>' %}
{{ 'layout.logged_in_as'|trans({'%username%': boldUsername}, 'FOSUserBundle')|raw }}

Answer (score 1):

```
<strong>{{ 'layout.logged_in_as'|trans({'%username%': app.user.username}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</strong>
```

Everything between the `{{ }}` twig parenthesis will be evaluated to a string, so this would be equivalent to:

```
<strong>Username</strong>
```

Comment: But this would make all of the 'layout.logged_in_as' message bold, not just the username, wouldn't it?

Comment: you are right, I misunderstood the question.  Take a look at @Martin Lie s answer, it looks like that is what you want